# Java Files not loading in jar

Tags: java, file, jar, resources, filenotfoundexception

I have a program that accesses a few files from a resources folder inside the source folder. When I access them with the code below, it works perfectly in Eclipse, but when I export the files as a runnable jar file, it doesn't work.
Here is my project structure

[image]

and code I use to load and play sound files:

```
public void playSound(String filename){

    try{

        File soundfile = new File(ChatClientCore.class.getResource("/resources/"+filename).getFile());
        AudioInputStream soundIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundfile);
        AudioFormat format = soundIn.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(soundIn);
        clip.start();
        while(clip.isRunning()){

            Thread.yield();

        }
        //clip.close();

    }catch(Exception ex){

        System.out.println("Error playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }   

}
```

And here is the error I get when I attempt to run the jar file outside of eclipse.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/randomDoorClose.wav (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:164)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1179)
at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientCore.playSound(ChatClientCore.java:181)
at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientWindow$4.mouseClicked(ChatClientWindow.java:203)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Edit: What my objective here is to load a `.wav` file from the resources package and play it. I am looking for a way that this will work from within a jar file, since right now it only works in Eclipse.

Comment: Did you try `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: Wouldn't that be just trimming what I have down by one line? As far as I know, it gets a resource and gives you the stream. I just did what I did since this is my first time using the Audio libraries, but please tell me if there is a difference.

Comment: What exactly is `resources` folder in your application? Is it package or some folder you manually added?

Comment: It is a package in the source folder, along with main package in my source folder.

Comment: Could you post screen of your project structure including where this file is located?

Comment: Yes, here is the hierarchy: http://imgur.com/a/wQRk0